# Java Web Start and database details in jnlp

Tags: java, mysql, database, java-web-start

Is it possible to hide database details in `jnlp`-file? My app use `jws` and `MySQL`-database. In `jnlp`-file i have defined db connection details (username, pw, hostname).

Like this:

```
property name="dbuser" value="username"
```

Is there any alternative ways to define database details? Details must be easy to change!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [JnlpDownloadServlet Guide: Substitutions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/downloadservletguide.html#substitutions).

> `JnlpDownloadServlet` makes convenient substitutions in your JNLP files. When the client requests a JNLP file, the servlet reads the original file, substitutes values, and returns the results.

---

> Is it possible to hide database details in jnlp-file?

No.  Not to a power user.

Answer (score 1):

The app probably shouldn't be talking directly to the database unless you trust all your users.  Instead, you should hide your database behind a service, for example a REST service.

Answer (score 0):

Never trust the client. The user can modify your program to do what they want and they can read anything you store on their system or anything sent over the network. Even if you use encryption, if it is decrypted on their computer then they can read it.

It is not a good idea to hide a secret on someone's computer and hope they don't see it. Even less so when your program is frequently reading this secret, making its location obvious.

You should assume that somewhere you have a hostile user who has modified your program (that runs on their computer) to do their bidding, and they know all the information you send to their computer.

You could create a database user for each of your users and still let them connect directly to your database, where their database user has very limited access. I think this would also be a bad idea. Databases often don't have the best security.

Instead, firewall off your database and only let your internal systems access it directly. Your users (through your java app) can instead access a web service like Chris suggested. This gives you a much smaller attack surface, which is easier to secure.